# The pythonian one-liner to associate list of dict and list of list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given a list of items [musicians] and a list of dictionaries [instrumets] how would one make the association between them in a **pythonic way?**

So to **simplify** my real scenario consider the followings:

```
musicians  = [[700,"James","Hetfield", "jh@metallica.com","N/A"],
              [701,"Lars","Ulrich","lu@metallica.com","N/A"],
              [702,"Kirk","Hammett","kh@metallica.com","N/A"],
              [703,"Robert","Trujillo", "rt@metallica.com","N/A"]]

instruments= ({700:"guitar"},{701:"drums"})
```

My objective is to replace the N/A is musicians with the instrument in instruments.

the code below will do the trick (but the intuition comes from java/c++)

```
for m in musicians:
    for i in instruments:
        if m[0] in i:
            m[4]=i[m[0]]
```

and the correct desired result would be:

```
[[700, 'James', 'Hetfield', 'jh@metallica.com', 'guitar'], [701, 'Lars', 'Ulrich', 'lu@metallica.com', 'drums'], [702, 'Kirk', 'Hammett', 'kh@metallica.com', 'N/A'], [703, 'Robert', 'Trujillo', 'rt@metallica.com', 'N/A']]
```

Q: Is there a classic way to do it in python?

Comment: why are `instrumets` a tuple of dicts and not a dict?

Comment: yes make `instrumets` a single dict then you can do something like `[m[:3] + [instrumets.get(m[0],m[4])] for m in musicians]`

Comment: @Ev. Kounis good question! I'm oversimplifying a real scenario where I'm given a list of dictionaries

Comment: Are there duplicate keys in those dicts?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D consider no dups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) to combine your instrument mappings, then use a list comprehension:

```
from collections import ChainMap

cm = ChainMap(*instruments)
musicians = [[*x[:-1], cm.get(x[0], x[-1])] for x in musicians]

print(musicians)

# [[700, 'James', 'Hetfield', 'jh@metallica.com', 'guitar'],
#  [701, 'Lars', 'Ulrich', 'lu@metallica.com', 'drums'],
#  [702, 'Kirk', 'Hammett', 'kh@metallica.com', 'N/A'],
#  [703, 'Robert', 'Trujillo', 'rt@metallica.com', 'N/A']]
```

Answer (score 3):

If there are no duplicate keys in list of dicts then merge those

```
musicians = [[700, "James", "Hetfield", "jh@metallica.com", "N/A"],
             [701, "Lars", "Ulrich", "lu@metallica.com", "N/A"],
             [702, "Kirk", "Hammett", "kh@metallica.com", "N/A"],
             [703, "Robert", "Trujillo", "rt@metallica.com", "N/A"]]

instrumets = ({700: "guitar"}, {701: "drums"})

instruments_dict = {}
for d in instrumets:
    instruments_dict.update(d)
for m in musicians:
    m[-1] = instruments_dict.get(m[0], m[-1]) # thanks to  Ev. Kounis
```

Comment: You might want to change the last line into `m[-1] = instruments_dict.get(m[0], m[-1])`. It is obvious from the example that not all instrument codes (702, etc) exist.

Comment: Btw provided there are no duplicates constructing the instruments_dict could be a one liner as in `dict(itertools.chain.from_iterable(d.items() for d in instrumets))`

Comment: Why does this depend on the existence of duplicates?

Comment: A very confusing alternative would also be `dict(*zip(*map(lambda x: x.items(), instrumets)))`